# How to transcribe this nullish coalescing operator with added equal mark to regular ternary operator

Tags: javascript

How would this shortcut nullish operator be in the plain ternary operator syntax

```
obj = obj[array[i]] ??= {}
```

What is confusing for me here is the added = after the two ??

Comment: `obj = (obj[array[i]] != null) ? obj[array[i]] : {}`

Answer (score 2):

The logical nullish assignment (x ??= y) operator only assigns if x is nullish (null or undefined).

in your question,

if obj[array[i]] equals to null or undefined, then obj[array[i]] will be {}.

checkout the mdn documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Comment: what about the first part obj =
how would you rewrite the whole expression to regular ternary operator?

Comment: `(obj[array[i]] !== null && obj[array[i]] !== undefined)` is equal to `(obj[array[i]] != null)`

Comment: And `obj[array[i]] ? obj[array[i]] : {}` is entirely different to the above expressions thus also not equal to the [Logical nullish assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) for it will recognize (and not let pass) any falsy value and not just (sanitize) `undefined` and `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I've removed that part from the answer.